# Microsoft Auth + Downstream Token Acquisition - Dataverse API - Umbraco 11

Tags: asp.net-core, umbraco, azure-ad-msal, dataverse

I use AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp() for user authentication to my web application, with EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi() and AddInMemoryTokenCaches() to later consume the Dataverse API using GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(). This is working well.

When I try and hook this up to my CMS as an external identity provider (Umbraco 11), the authentication works, but I get an error when trying to acquire the access token - I think as there are now multiple authentication schemes present.

I tried to pass the correct scheme in as one of the parameters:

```
var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes, "UmbracoMembers.OpenIdConnect", null, null, null, null);
```

But I get the following error

Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user. See https://aka.ms/ms-id-web/ca_incremental-consent.
Source=Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition
StackTrace:
at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.d__14.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.d__18.MoveNext()
at UmbracoDataversePortal.Shared.Components.SubmissionForm.SubmissionFormViewComponent.

Inner Exception 1:
MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call.

I also tried a completely different approach like so:

```
var authBuilder = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:ClientId"))
             .WithTenantId(_configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:TenantId"))
             .Build();

        string[] scopes = { _configuration.GetValue<string>("DataverseConfig:BaseUri") + "/user_impersonation" };

        var accounts = await authBuilder.GetAccountsAsync();

 AuthenticationResult tokenResult;
        if (accounts.Any())
        {
            tokenResult = await authBuilder.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                                            .ExecuteAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            tokenResult = await authBuilder.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                                            .ExecuteAsync();
        }
```

But this did not work either - no accounts were returned and the attempt to acquire interactively failed (plus I really don't think this is what I want anyway).

Spent hours and hours trying to get this to work - have got a workaround (using S2S auth instead and then passing the UPN of the logged in user to a custom field when creating / updating records), but would love to  crack it after all this time.